# C header files and dynamic linking error

Tags: c, header-files, dynamic-library

I have created a dynamically linked library. The only problem I have is that my main program does not recognize my header file. The header file is in a separate folder from my main program. I have tried `#include "myheader.h"` as well as `#include "/folder/dir/myheader.h"`

Here is what my .h consist of

```
    extern int afunction(int,int);
    extern int afunction(int,int);
```

So far this code works

```
    gcc -fPIC -c filename1.c
    gcc -fPIC -c filename2.c

    gcc -shared -o libMylib.so filename1.o filename2.o
```

I then copy the lib to `/usr/local/lib`, and then

```
    gcc main.c -L. -lMylib -o exeName -ldl
```

and I get

```
    " myheader.h : no such file or directory.
```

Here is my directory structure:

directory1 ----------------folder1(main program.c)

directory1 ----------------folder2(myheader.h, along with functions for the pgm)

A push in the right direction would help, as I have written all my code and I am just at the last phase.

Comment: Try making the path in your main absolute. If that works then you have a pathing error.

Answer (score 3):

You need `gcc ... -I<some directory to myheader.h>`. That will enable the compiler to find the header file.

Comment: Are you comping into object code, if so look up the `I`flag. Otherwise if linking look up the -L flag and the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`environment variable. It is on the manual page

Comment: i think i figured it out. i dont have the code for the pointers and what not in my main program.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your lib header files in the same folder with your current program.

or like @Ed Heal said.. adding `-I<path>` for include header folder.